# "xacro: in-order processing became default in ROS Melodic. You can drop the option" error

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

https://github.com/EuropeanRoverChallenge/ERC-Remote-Maintenance-Sim
Using the link I wrote all commands which is given in "Install on the host system" section.

When I try this command:

```
$ roslaunch ur3_sim simulation.launch
```

It gives error like this:

```
    ... logging to /home/ubuntu4/.ros/log/f2319ee2-b808-11ed-bb34-1be4f5885cab/roslaunch-ubuntu4-6223.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take a while.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

xacro: in-order processing became default in ROS Melodic. You can drop the option.
No such file or directory: /home/ubuntu4/catkin_ws3/src/universal_robot/ur_description/urdf/common.gazebo.xacro [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/ubuntu4/catkin_ws3/src/universal_robot/ur_description/urdf/common.gazebo.xacro'
when processing file: /home/ubuntu4/catkin_ws3/src/UR3_sim/ur3_sim_description/urdf/ur3_sim.urdf.xacro
RLException: while processing /home/ubuntu4/catkin_ws3/src/UR3_sim/ur3_sim_gazebo/launch/ur3_sim.launch:
while processing /home/ubuntu4/catkin_ws3/src/UR3_sim/ur3_sim_description/launch/ur3_sim_upload.launch:
Invalid <param> tag: Cannot load command parameter [robot_description]: command [['/opt/ros/noetic/lib/xacro/xacro', '--inorder', '/home/ubuntu4/catkin_ws3/src/UR3_sim/ur3_sim_description/urdf/ur3_sim.urdf.xacro', 'transmission_hw_interface:=hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface']] returned with code [2]. 

Param xml is <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro --inorder '$(find ur3_sim_description)/urdf/ur3_sim.urdf.xacro' transmission_hw_interface:=$(arg transmission_hw_interface)"/>
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/412972/%22xacro:-in-order-processing-became-default-in-ros-melodic.-you-can-drop-the-option%22-error/) by [Speedtail765](https://answers.ros.org/users/135363/speedtail765/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2023-03-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `--inorder` warning message in the title to this question is not the actual problem here.

The error "No such file" indicates that your `UR3_sim/ur3_sim_description/urdf/ur3_sim.urdf.xacro` file is not compatible with the newest `universal_robot` ros package. You need to fix the file paths inside that file.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2023-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0